# Unable to send XML data using PHP sockets

Tags: php, xml, web-services, sockets, soap

I'm trying to connect to a web service, through a proxy, that uses SOAP. The catch is I can't use cURL and I can't add any modules that would make this SOAP message any easier to write, I have to manually create the XML for the message and send it over through my proxy. The good news is I'm actually able to establish a connection to the web service, the only problem is every response back I receive says: 'Empty message - no data received'. Can anyone see what about my socket is doing wrong in sending over the XML:

```
/*this is just striped of personal info, 
the XML I'm actually using is valid since 
on my development environment (which has cURL) 
will successfully get results with this XML*/

$request  = '<soapenv:Envelope>';
$request .= '<soapenv:Header>';
$request .=     '</soapenv:Header>';
$request .=     '<soapenv:Body>';
$request .=     '</soapenv:Body>';
$request .= '</soapenv:Envelope>';

$fp = fsockopen($proxy, 80, $errno, $errstr, 100);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\r\n";
} else {
    $out  = "POST " . $path . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: " . $host . "\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($request) . "\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $out .= "SOAPAction: \"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"\r\n";
    $out .= "Accept: text/xml\n";
    $out .= "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth\r\n"; 
    $out .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    $out .= $request;
    $output = '';
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $output .= fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
$output = trim(substr($output, strpos($output, "<?")));
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but the first line of the request misses the closing '>'.

Comment: Oops, yeah that is a typo, sorry about that, just fixed. The real XML I use to send to the service I know is valid since my development environment can send it over using cURL no problem.

Comment: Can you capture with Wireshark the request via cURL and the request via your app and compare the two?

Comment: I've been using fiddler to compare the headers and as far as I can tell they are identical.

Comment: And can you see also the body of the two requests in fiddler? Are they also the same?

Answer (score 0):

I worked a bit with HTTP in Java, this could help you.
Header fields are seperated by CRLF "\r\n":

..

```
$out  = "POST " . $path . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out .= "Host: " . $host . "\r\n";
```

..

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I changed the code to use \r\n instead of just \n, unfortunately, the result is the same.